# Guava Multimap merging consecutive items with same key

Tags: java, collections

I have been playing around with Guava Multimaps and I ran into an issue with tracking when an user is damaged (more the way it's displayed, really)

Let's say I have a `Multimap<User, Hit>` and `Hit` consists of 2 fields: damager (string), and damage (double).

---

Here is an example of what my collection might look like:

1. dangerous01, 6
2. dangerous01, 4
3. dangerous01, 1
4. dangerous03, 9
5. dangerous01, 3

The way I displayed this would result in something like this:

```
dangerous01 dealt 6 damage
dangerous01 dealt 4 damage
dangerous01 dealt 1 damage
dangerous03 dealt 9 damage
dangerous01 dealt 3 damage
```

But I would want it to look like this instead:

```
dangerous01 dealt 11 damage
dangerous03 dealt 9 damage
dangerous01 dealt 3 damage
```

The order in the collection is based on insert so that might be useful information. I'm also using streams right now to iterate through the `Hit`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might want is Multiset, another Guava collection.  From one perspective, a multiset is just a collection that condenses duplicates to save memory.  But it can also be viewed as a map of objects to counts.  Each user could then have a `Multiset<String>` field.  To record damage, you would simply do `user.damagers.add(damager, count);`  This updates the amount of damage dealt by `damager` by the given value.

Unfortunately, this would require you to use integer damage values.  If you can't do that, you'd have to use a basic Map and check if the value is null before updating it, as GlenPeterson suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a multimap instead of a map?  Instead of (Pseudocode):

```
Multimap.put(someUser, newDamage)
```

Use a regular map:

```
Damage currentDam = map.get(someUser)
if (currentDam == null) {
    currentDam = 0;
}
map.put(someUser, currentDam + newDamage)
```

If you need the multimap for some other reason, you could use the same technique to summarize the results you already have in your multimap.

Comment: My example in the original post isn't exactly what I'm going to be doing and Multimap is imo better to use for the thing I'm doing.